# Read lines from a text file into variables

Tags: python, file, lines

I have two different functions in my program, one writes an output to a txt file (function A) and the other one reads it and should use it as an input (function B).

Function A works just fine (although i'm always open to suggestions on how i could improve).
It looks like this:

```
def createFile():
    fileName = raw_input("Filename: ")
    fileNameExt = fileName + ".txt" #to make sure a .txt extension is used

    line1 = "1.1.1"
    line2 = int(input("Enter line 2: ")
    line3 = int(input("Enter line 3: ")

    file = (fileNameExt, "w+")
    file.write("%s\n%s\n%s" % (line1, line2, line3))
    file.close()

    return
```

This appears to work fine and will create a file like

```
1.1.1
123
456
```

Now, function B should use that file as an input. This is how far i've gotten so far:

```
def loadFile():
    loadFileName = raw_input("Filename: ")
    loadFile = open(loadFileName, "r")

    line1 = loadFile.read(5)
```

That's where i'm stuck, i know how to use this first 5 characters but i need line 2 and 3 as variables too.

Comment: Which part of this are you stuck on? Where is your code, and what precisely is the problem with it? The "variable variables" is a bad idea, I would read the file and store each line in a dictionary `{'A': 123, ...}`.

Comment: this is not a good idea ... you probably dont really want to do this ... just get it as a list or a dictionary as @jonrsharpe suggests ... magic variables are usually frowned upon...

Comment: Sorry, i hope my updated question is more clear.. @jonrsharpe a library indeed seems what i want, but i don't know how to get the data from the file into the library... And, just so i know, why is it a bad idea to use  "variable variables"?

Comment: It's a bad idea because why would you want to fill your namespace with `line1`, `line2`, ..., `lineN` when you could have a single list `lines` and access e.g. `lines[n]`? That also makes it easier to do `for line in lines:`, which would be a huge pain with individual names. And what do you mean "library"? If you mean "dictionary", [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: @jonrsharpe i indeed meant dictionary sorry, i'll have another look at the documentation

Answer (score 3):

```
f = open('file.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

`lines` is what you want

Other option:

```
f = open( "file.txt", "r" )
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
f.close()
```

More read:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
my_data = dict(zip(ascii_uppercase,open("some_file_to_read.txt"))
print my_data["A"]
```

this will store them in a dictionary with lettters as keys ... if you really want to cram it into variables(note that in general this is a **TERRIBLE** idea) you can do

```
globals().update(my_data)
print A
```