# How to store a html file in a variable as a string in python

Tags: python

I have html file and I want to store the contents of that file in a variable as a string value. I have tried this but it returns a blank string. How can I do this?

```
def myfunc():
    str = ""
    with open("/home/suman/Alert_logo_report.html") as report_file:
        raw_html = report_file.readlines()
        str = ''.join(raw_html)
    return str
```

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407571/read-lines-from-a-text-file-into-variables

Comment: Thanks for reference but in that answer it stores value as a list but I want as a string. @RafaelOsipov

Comment: use report_file.read() instead of readlines. This will read the entire document to a string.

Comment: I don't know why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Your file is empty. if it was not you would see something so whether you call read or readlines is irrelevant as you have nothing in the file. Also using str as a variable name is a bad idea and you don't need to declare variables in python.

Comment: Don't name a variable `str`. This shadows the built-in [`str` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str).

Comment: Yeah I'm also guessing the file is empty: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/425ed8d9-e24a-4e3b-bc1d-98e7869eaf6a/

Comment: Your code could be a simple `return report_file.read().replace('\n','')` (inside the `with`, no string variables involved) if you really want to throw away the line breaks, or without the `replace()` if you need them. But otherwise the problem itself is probably that your file is just empty. Perhaps you overwrote it in an earlier attempt or later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I don't see that behavior:

```
def get_content(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        raw_lines = f.readlines()
    content = ''.join(raw_lines)
    return content
```

gives me the HTML content.

On the other hand:
-you're overwriting `str` that is a basic python function transforming something in a string. I cannot see this ending well (meaning: I've done it in the past, it wasn't pretty)
-there is not need to declare a variable, this is python
-I don't understand why reading lines, then joining them without doing anything.

The way I see it, this would be better:

```
def get_content(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        raw = f.read()
    return raw
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"""string_literal"""` instead of `"string_literal"` or `'string_literal'`. """string_literal""" is for multi line strings. This will work.

```
def myfunc():
str = """"""
with open("employees.html") as report_file:
    raw_html = report_file.readlines()
    str = """""".join(raw_html)
return str
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
f = open("0101.html", "r")
str1 = f.readlines()
print(str1)
f.close()
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).